# using methods to sum up numbers digits

Tags: java, methods

This code is designed for summing up the digits of the number but it brings up

```
javac Root.java Root.java:17: error: '.class' expected
```

Who can explain what is the problem here. Also i want to make the same program using Arrays but i have problems with putting int in Array, if you have suggestions i am glade to here you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Root {

    public static int numRoot(int n, int sum){
        while (n != 0) {
            sum = sum + n % 10; 
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number here");
        int n = in.nextInt(); 
        int root = numRoot(int sum, int n);
        System.out.print("the sum of the digits off given num is " + root);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `sum` in your function?

Answer (score 3):

You have error here, Correct it.

```
int root = numRoot(int sum, int n); // this is wrong
```

Change it to

```
int root = numRoot(n,sum); // should use correct order of input parameters
```

Comment: YYeah! thanks a lot it corrected the error but now i have problems with summation, i will correct that in a  moment

Comment: still not correct, you should change it to `numRoot(n, sum)`

Comment: really what's the difference ??? oh yeah it really works now, can you explain it pleas

Comment: @user3791431 look at your method, n should be first parameter, follow by sum, the other way will always return 0

Comment: @user3791431 now you can see you are getting correct value for `sum`

Comment: Yes you are wright, but even if i write vise versa in method and main function why it does not works correct?

Comment: @user3791431 `numRoot(n,sum);` method consider first argument as input number and second as `sum`

Comment: Do you have any ideas of solving the same problem using Arrays

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57377/discussion-between-user3791431-and-ruchira-gayan-ranaweera).

Comment: how you are going to use arrays here?

Answer (score 0):

This should be your method, you do not need to pass sum:

```
   public static int numRoot(int n){
        int sum=0;
        while (n != 0) {
            sum += n % 10; 
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

and you shall call it like this:

```
int root = numRoot(n);
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer Agree. in his program its `0`